# Azure Cognitive Services - why don't i have access to service? (401 error)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am writing a .Net Core web application, where I use [Azure - Computer Vision](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/).

I am doing everything as it is shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vs-computer-vision-connected-service

and my problem is:

Computer Vision API results:

> { "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }

I don't know what is wrong. I have suitable key and right endpoint. I checked also all of the things that are here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2017/05/17/http-401-access-denied-when-calling-azure-cognitive-services-apis/

Here is my code:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // TODO: Change this to your image's path on your site. 
        string imagePath = @"images/family.jpg";

        // Enable static files such as image files. 
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        string visionApiKey = "";
        string visionApiEndPoint = "ComputerVisionAPI_ServiceEndPoint";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Request headers.
        // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", visionApiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "");

        // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
        string requestParameters = "visualFeatures=Categories,Description,Color&language=en";

        // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
       // string uri = visionApiEndPoint + "/analyze" + "?" + requestParameters;
        string uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0" + "/analyze" + "?" + requestParameters;


        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body. Posts an image you've added to your site's images folder. 
        var fileInfo = env.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(imagePath);
        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(fileInfo.PhysicalPath);

        string contentString = string.Empty;
        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
            // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            // Execute the REST API call.
            response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

            // Get the JSON response.
            contentString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>Cognitive Services Demo</h1>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<p><b>Test Image:</b></p>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<div><img src=\"" + imagePath + "\" /></div>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<p><b>Computer Vision API results:</b></p>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonPrettyPrint(contentString));
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where did you create the endpoint to generate the keys? It can be a bit confusing since you can create keys through the cognitive services site and through the Azure portal.

Comment: @Zan, please don't post your keys to this or any forum.  You should edit you question and roll your keys

Comment: @JoeyCai, thanks for your answer. I've changed my endpoint:
 https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0
https://imgur.com/b7el0P5 <--- here is my overview. But now i have different error: Computer Vision API results:

{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

I checked status and location in properities and everything is correct.
What else could be wrong?

Comment: @Jon I created my endpoint through the Azure portal.

Comment: It seems that you missed the trailing slash and at the end of endpoint. You could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-iOS/issues/37).

Comment: It is ok:        string uri = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0" + " /analyze" + "?" + requestParameters;
I have trailing slash before analyze.

Comment: UPDATE: I don't know what was wrong, but it works now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the **same region** in your REST API call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.

First, **you must find the location of your subscription**. In order to find the location of your subscription region, you must go to Cognitive Services -> Properties under the Label Location, you will find your subscription region. See below.

Second **you must find the correct endpoint to make the call to**. For example, if I want to make a call to the Computer Vision API, My location is East US, I will use either key 1 or 2, then I will use the following endpoint East US - `https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect`

You will now be able to have access to the API.

For more details about troubleshoot, you could refer to this [article](https://ittechnews.net/microsoft/official-microsoft-news/azure-cognitive-services-authentication-error-http-401-access-denied-due-to-invalid-subscription-key-make-sure-to-provide-a-valid-key-for-an-active-subscription/) and this [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2017/05/17/http-401-access-denied-when-calling-azure-cognitive-services-apis/).

Comment: Setting the region correctly worked for me. The C# sample [for the Translator Text API v3](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-C-Sharp-Tutorial) did not work for me until I changed the region from "westus" to "global".

Comment: Sorry, it wan't my question, so I can't accept it as the answer.